# error with phpunit execution: how to set PHP Test class path in phpunit.xml?

Tags: 8, testing

I installed the conditional_fields module:

the tree is the following:

```
root project
  - phpunit.xml
  - web
    - modules
      - conditional_fields
        - tests
          - src
            - FunctionalJavascript
            - Unit
              - ConditionalFieldControllerTest.php
```

and this is the declaration of the php class I want to test:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\conditional_fields\Unit;

use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;

use Drupal\conditional_fields\Controller\ConditionalFieldController;

    /**
     * ConditionalFieldController units tests.
     *
     * In unit testing, there should be as few dependencies as possible.
     * We want the smallest number of moving parts to be interacting in
     * our test, or we won't be sure where the errors are, or whether our
     * tests passed by accident.
     *
     * @ingroup conditional_fields
     *
     * @group conditional_fields
     */
    class ConditionalFieldControllerTest extends UnitTestCase {
     ....
    }
```

In the phpunit.xml file I wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         verbose="true"
        >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="drupal-composer-project tests">
            <directory>web/modules/conditional_fields/tests/src/Unit</directory>
            <file>ConditionalFieldControllerTest</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaltest2\web\modules\conditional_fields\tests\src\Unit\ConditionalFieldControllerTest.php on line 21
```

Comment: I think you need to use the bootstrap file from phpunit.xml.dist at Drupal root folder not the vendor autoload

Comment: I changed the path of the autoload file inside phpunuit.xml and I set it to web / autoload.php but the error remains

Comment: For accuracy web / autoload.php points to the autoload file inside the vendor folder, so it does not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must point in the phpunit.xml file to drupal's bootstrap.php file. See a working phpunit.xml file example for Drupal 8 here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/permissions_by_term/tree/tests/phpunit.xml.dist